# Asynchronous Spring REST call for Work Executor Sample

Tags: spring, rest

I am developing work executor software. So far this is designed in the following way:

1. Client will invoke on URL which will call on a Spring REST controller method
2. The REST controller gets a bean "WorkAcceptor" which is configured as "prototype".
3. The class "WorkAcceptor" creates a bean object called "WorkQInserter" and pass the request to "enqueueTasks()" of "WorkQInserter". After calling the enqueueTasks() it sends out generated work id to the client.
4. The method "enqueueTasks()" is called on the bean object which stores the request in Oracle AQ
5. A single background thread "WorkExecutor" continuosly runs which pops out request from the AQ and forwards the request to another singleton object "WorkExecutor" for processing
6. The "WorkExecutor" executes the work as reuested and stores the result in Oracle DB and it requires roughly 30-40 secs to complete the process

Note that the WorkExecutor gets request from FIFO Q and executes the same and stores in DB.
The client has to check the status of the work later (with the reference workid received at step # 3) by calling on a different REST (for retrieve work status).

I have almost nil knowledge in asynchronous method call. 
I want to know what changes have to do to the REST controller in #1 or any other associated classes to make the REST call asynchronous? Such that the client calls on the REST asynchronously, get accepted response, request pushed in AQ, "WorkExecutor" pops out request from AQ and executes work, stores in DB and callback success/failure on the client.

Please observe my code snippets. The beans are configured in spring configuration bean xml file.

Any idea with some sample will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance and forgive me for the long post.

### REST controller

```
@RestController
public class WorkExecutorRESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/workexecutor/{workdetails}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> executeWork( @PathVariable String workdetails ) 
    {
        WorkAcceptor l_WorkAcceptor = WorkerBeanFactory.getBeanForId("WorkAcceptor"); //configured as prototype bean
        Integer result = l_WorkAcceptor.sendWork(workdetails);
        return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(result,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

### WorkAcceptor class

```
public class WorkAcceptor {

    public Integer sendWork(String workdetails)
    {
        WorkQInserter l_WorkQInserter = WorkerBeanFactory.getBeanForId("WorkQInserter"); //configured as prototype bean

        // Here generate the work id

        if(l_WorkQInserter.enqueueTasks(workdetails, workid) == SUCCESSFUL)
        {
            return workid; //this goes back to client as reference id
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

### WorkQInserter class

```
public class WorkQInserter {

    public Integer WorkQInserter(String workdetails, Integer workid)
    {
        //PUSH THE DATA IN ORACLE AQ
        //RETURN SUCCESS OR FAILURE
    }
}
```

### WorkExecutor class

```
//This class is configured as singleton in bean xml. During initialization it runs a dedicated thread
//which periodically pops out request from the AQ and process

public class WorkExecutor {

    public Integer execute()
    {
        //POPS OUT THE REQUEST FROM ORACLE AQ
        //EXECUTE WORK
        //RETURN SUCCESS OR FAILURE
    }
}
```

Comment: Your web service accepts the call and put's them into a queue. You return the Process Handle to the Client which he can use to query the status. Btw. in this case you should return HTTP Status Code 202 "Accepted" rather than OK.  That's already asynchronous. What's the reason for adding additional complexity to the REST Service by making it asynchronous?

Comment: Thanks for commenting andih. The server executes the task and generate some details when finish. The requirement is to callback the details to client silently when done. Otherwise the client has to fetch it from server by passing the task reference and may be try again if still the task in progress.

Comment: The requirement is that the client gets push notifications or that some kind of callback method will be invoked or that the incoming request should wait for the answer. The worker will actively notify the clients when he's finished or do you want to poll the database? If the worker notifies the interested parties / clients how, via rest call, via response queue, via event bus, ... ? You need some kind of response channel. Which is not defined until now.

Comment: @andih, requirement is that some kind of callback method needs to be invoked on client. And the response channel is not defined, true. Basically the "WorkExecutor " you see runs a dedicated thread in server, which picks up request from the AQ. Then it processes and stores in DB. This is the endpoint where the task finishes. So, I am having some idea to initiate a callback to client from this place, if possible at all. Although I have to identify the request or task is for which client.

Comment: For a callback solution you need some callback method on the client which you will invoke. The client may either pass it per invocation or you may use a configured callback endpoint for all requests. What are the requirements regarding invocation of the callback. Is it allowed to loose some of the callbacks or must the callback and the database call be "transactional".  If "transactional" is it possible to use XA transactions. Is it required to invoke the callback immediately or can it be delayed? What should happen if the client is not reachable due to network problems?

Comment: I am looking for a configured callback endpoint for all requests. The callback will happen whenever database commit successful. If the client is not reachable due to network reason then callback will fail and the client later has to get back from server using different REST. Not thinking of any retry at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comments above:

- A configured callback endpoint for all requests exits.
- Callbacks must not be invoked transactional
- Callbacks may be lost.

The work is done asynchronous by the *WorkExecutor*. The client immediately gets a handle with the *workId* which it may use to query the  status if the callback gets lost. The *WorkExectutor* informs the client via the configured callback endpoint about the final status of the work.

i.e. the **WorkExecutor** looks something like:

```
public class WorkExecutor {

    public Integer execute()
    {
        //POPS OUT THE REQUEST FROM ORACLE AQ
        //EXECUTE WORK

        // invoke client callback passing the workId
        // workId should be available form the queue
        // callback endpoint is static / configurable fix for all requests 
        // successStatus is the status whether the request was fulfilled successfully or even not.
        notifyClient(workId, successStatus);
    }
}
```

And your **RestController**:

```
@RestController
public class WorkExecutorRESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/workexecutor/{workdetails}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> executeWork( @PathVariable String workdetails ) 
    {
        WorkAcceptor l_WorkAcceptor = WorkerBeanFactory.getBeanForId("WorkAcceptor"); //configured as prototype bean
        Integer result = l_WorkAcceptor.sendWork(workdetails);
        return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(result,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED); // accepted rather than 200 / OK
    }
}
```

There is no need to make the REST Service itself asynchronous.